# How to evaluate Work Done by two forces expressed in different variables

Tags: forces, energy-conservation

Say you want to evaluate the distance a ball moves when projected with a speed of u, if it experiences a resistive ground friction force $F_g$ which is a constant term ${\mu}R$ and a force from air resistance $F_a$ gives as a function of velocity.

Conservation of energy allows you to say $KE_{init}$ = $F_g*x$ + (work done by air resistance)

How should I find the work done by F(v), say if $F(v) =$ $mgv^2$?

I want to integrate wrt x but since $v = dx/dt$ I feel uncomfortable doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of "resistive ground friction force $F_g$" are you referring to?

Comment: integrate wrt time!

Comment: @BobD The friction betweel the ball and the surface it moves on, which is why I gave it as   mu*R. But you could call it F really; what I don't understand is how to account for both forces in a useful way.

Comment: @SmarthBansal Why does integrating F(v) wrt t give me the work done? Please can you explain further

Comment: @Pandaa But what kind of friction? Static? Kinetic? Rolling resistance?

Comment: Force $\times dx = $ Force $\times dx/dt \times dt = Fvdt$